# Sum one row of a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I'd like to sum one particular row of a large NumPy array. I know the function `array.max()` will give the maximum across the whole array, and `array.max(1)` will give me the maximum across each of the rows as an array. However, I'd like to get the maximum in a certain row (for example, row 7, or row 29). I have a large array, so getting the maximum for all rows will give me a significant time penalty.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can easily access a row of a two-dimensional array using the indexing operator.  The row itself is an array, a view of a part of the original array, and exposes all array methods, including `sum()` and `max()`.  Therefore you can easily get the maximum per row like this:

```
x = arr[7].max()   # Maximum in row 7
y = arr[29].sum()  # Sum of the values in row 29
```

Just for completeness, you can do the same for columns:

```
z = arr[:, 5].sum()  # Sum up all values in column 5.
```